# Using a PIC18F25K22 as both master and slave at the same time with SP1 and SPI2

Tags: pic, spi

I want to use SPI1 on a 18F series PIC as master and then use SPI2 on the same PIC as a slave to another PIC ? Can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. In fact there would be little point providing two serial modules if you were then constrained to use them in the same way.

As it says in [the datasheet](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC18F25K22):

[image: independent]

Note that each operates *independently* from the other. Also, for each module in SPI mode:

[image: slave]

You can see that both master and slave modes are supported.

Each MSSP module has its own set of registers, which are used to configure each module as required.

Comment: Thanks, I had some problems when using te AD7793 from analogue devices , the source file provided by the manufacturer has a function for SPI_read and SPI_write. When I initialiazed the1 SPI1_Init_Advanced as well as the SPI2,  the main.c program stopped working. As soon as one is commented out, it started working again.(All the hardware was connected correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I use the AD7793 as well, but I've rolled my own SPI_READ and SPI_WRITE macros. These macros work on 16-bit processors, and maybe on 32-bit (I have not tried). The first parameter passed is the SPI port number (e.g. 1 or 2). They work in slave and master mode.

e.g. SPI_WRITE(1, 'H'); or SPI_READ(2, char_to_send, char_to_receive_data);

```
  #define  _SPI_WRITE_final(_SPIBUF, _SPIRBF, _SPIROV, ch)             \
     _SPIROV = 0;                                                      \
     while (_SPIRBF)                                                   \
        __asm__ volatile ("mov %0, w0" : : "g"(_SPIBUF) : "cc", "w0"); \
     _SPIBUF = (uint8_t)(ch);                                          \
     __asm__ volatile ("nop");                                         \
     while (!_SPIRBF);
  #define  _SPI_WRITE_int(bus, ch)                                     \
     _SPI_WRITE_final(SPI##bus##BUF, SPI##bus##STATbits.SPIRBF,        \
     SPI##bus##STATbits.SPIROV, ch)
  #define  _SPI_WRITE(bus, ch)              do {_SPI_WRITE_int(bus, ch);} while(0)

  #define  _SPI_READ_final(_SPIBUF, _SPIRBF, _SPIROV, ch_out, ch_in)   \
     _SPIROV = 0;                                                      \
     while (_SPIRBF)                                                   \
        __asm__ volatile ("mov %0, w0" : : "g"(_SPIBUF) : "cc", "w0"); \
     _SPIBUF = (uint8_t)(ch_out);                                      \
     __asm__ volatile ("nop");                                         \
     while (!_SPIRBF);                                                 \
     ch_in = _SPIBUF;
  #define  _SPI_READ_int(bus, ch_out, ch_in)                           \
     _SPI_READ_final(SPI##bus##BUF, SPI##bus##STATbits.SPIRBF,         \
     SPI##bus##STATbits.SPIROV, ch_out, ch_in)
  #define  _SPI_READ(bus, ch_out, ch_in)    do {_SPI_READ_int(bus, ch_out, ch_in);} while(0)
```

Comment: Great, thanks ! Im using a 8bit PIC at the moment, but will have a good look at this code.